# Как, на C#, посмотреть температуру "железа"?

Tags: c#, .net

Я пробовал через using System.Management;

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData WHERE Active=True");
         foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
         {
             byte[] vendorSpec = obj["VendorSpecific"] as byte[];
             if (vendorSpec != null)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Температура = " + vendorSpec[115]);
             }

         }
```

Но получал исключение: System.Management.ManagementException: "Не поддерживается".
Погуглив наткнулся на...

"Не все машины поддерживают считывание температуры процессора. Это функция вашего программного обеспечения BIOS."(с)

У меня MacBook Pro..

Comment: Недавно видел в ролике AlexGyver похожую задачу. Возможно эти [исходники](https://github.com/AlexGyver/PCdisplay) помогут вам. там проект сбора информации о железе был на C#. Само видео [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCPOQI-eFYs).

Comment: Смотрите исходники OpenHardwareMonitor, она умеет очень многое показывать по железу, написана на C#